# Does Clojure recursion work backwards?

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm currently going through the 4clojure [Problem 23](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/23)

My current solution uses recursion to go through the list and append each element to the end of the result of the same function:

```
(fn self [x] (if (= x []) 
                   x 
             (conj (self (rest x)) (first x))
))
```

But when I run it against [1 2 3] it gives me (1 2 3)
What I think it should be doing through recursion is:

```
(conj (conj (conj (conj (conj [] 5) 4) 3) 2) 1)
```

which does return

```
[5 4 3 2 1]
```

But it is exactly the opposite, so I must be missing something. Also, I don't understand why ones return a vector and the other one returns a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `(rest v)` you're getting a list (not a vector), and then conj is appending to the front each time (not the back):

```
user=> (defn self [v] (if (empty? v) v (conj (self (rest v)) (first v))))
#'user/self
user=> (self [1 2 3])
(1 2 3)
user=> (defn self [v] (if (empty? v) [] (conj (self (rest v)) (first v))))
#'user/self
user=> (self [1 2 3])
[3 2 1]
user=>
user=> (rest [1])
()
user=> (conj '() 2)
(2)
user=> (conj '(2) 1)
(1 2)
user=>
```

Comment: although I understand now the reason (efficiency) it strikes me as weird having the same name for a function with a different behaviour.
But thank you for the explanation, it'll probably stick from now on :)

Comment: @Willyfrog: well the behaviour is simply "adding", without saying where (and *(doc conj)* mentions it).  For example you can also *conj* to, say, a set:  *(conj #{:a :c} :b)*

Comment: @Willyfrog You can use [`cons`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/cons) to always append to the front.

Comment: conj adds to the end of a vector or the beginning of a list.

Comment: @Willyfrog read this: http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/conj and also this: http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/into